# Parsing the column to get desired output

Tags: sql, sql-server

In one of the table I have column description in which error msg is stored.
The error msg can be any of the below format.

```
a.failed due to warnings.ERR: [] | WARNINGS: [war1,war2] | Warn_fina [war1,war2]  | otherErrors []
b.failed due to Errors.ERR: [Err1,Err2] | warnings: [war1,war2] | warn_fina [] | otherErrors []
c.Reading failed stacktrace bla bla.
d.othererror stacktrace bla bla.
```

Now I need to write a select query which selects all the columns but for this description column output I need like below

if it is of type a or b then output is :  Err1,Err2,War1,War2 
only the error and warnings in first two contetns in brackets.
if it is not of a or b then nothing should come for this column.

I think from oracle Reg expression is helpful.

Can we achieve the above criteria with just one select query?
Basically I need to get only the errorcodes, warning codes present in brackets. Means two subgroups from the string.

Comment: Try to use patterns in LIKE clause. (see also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: If I use like clause then I will loose other data which is of not like data. I need all the information in all columns.

Comment: Only extra condition is for the specified column value should be the null or comma separated war/err

Comment: Can't see a problem with LIKE.
make it in select with LEFT OUTER JOIN to the same table with LIKE statement.
As a result for your column use results from the joined table

Comment: Can u share your query, what have you tried?

Comment: I am trying to use REGEXP_REPLACE in my query.. But I couldn't make it correct query to replace unwanted string in my description column..

Comment: I need some REGEXP such way it gives only error codes and warning codes present in first two brackets

Answer (score 0):

I Could get only errors and warning using regexp_replace and regexp_substr functions.

I need one more thing can we write select *,regexp_replace() from a table?